# Add-Migration: Partial results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created two classes: Máquina(Machine) and TipoMáquina(Type of Machine), and also, I tried to give to the class Máquina a foreign Key from Tipo Máquina (Note: if was the first migration. There were no other tables):

```
namespace Plataforma.Models
{
    public class Máquina
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public int MáquinaId { get; set; }

        public int TipoMáquinaId { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoMáquina TipoMáquina { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Plataforma.Models
{
    public class TipoMáquina
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public int TipoMáquinaId { get; set; }
        public string DescripciónTipoMáq { get; set; }
        public int PesoKg { get; set; }
        public int AltoMt { get; set; }
        public int LargoMt { get; set; }
        public int AnchoMt { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Máquina> Máquinas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

They were also included in the DBContext:

```
    public class Plataforma: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Máquina> Máquinas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TipoMáquina> TipoMáquinas { get; set; }
    }
```

However, the result in the DataBase was only the first table. No sign of TipoMáquina or the foreing key in the Máquina table and I don't know why.

I suspect it has something to do with the migration, in the down() section:

```
    public partial class PrimeraRelación : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Máquina",
                c => new
                    {
                        MáquinaId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        TipoMáquinaId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.MáquinaId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.TipoMáquina", t => t.TipoMáquinaId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.TipoMáquinaId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.TipoMáquina",
                c => new
                    {
                        TipoMáquinaId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),

                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.TipoMáquinaId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Máquina", "TipoMáquinaId", "dbo.TipoMáquina");
            DropIndex("dbo.Máquina", new[] { "TipoMáquinaId" });
            DropTable("dbo.TipoMáquina");
            DropTable("dbo.Máquina");
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks correct. The Up() code is used to generate the SQL to update the database. Down() is only used if you rollback. Try generating a SQL script to see what is going on `update-database -Script`

Comment: Required attribute not needed either. By convention it will create required  identity columns.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following modifications in TipoMachinas:

```
private ICollection<Máquina> máquinas;


public virtual ICollection<Máquina> Máquinas 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.máquinas;
        }
        set
        {
            this.máquinas = value;
        }
    }
```

and in the constructor:

```
public TipoMáquina()
    {
        this.máquinas = new HashSet<Máquina>(); 
    }
```

also imho it will be better if you name your primary key Id's only Id instead of ModelId :)

and finally you can add virtual to dbcontext's dbsets

```
public class Plataforma: DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Máquina> Máquinas { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<TipoMáquina> TipoMáquinas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1) Virtual is not required on DbSets unless your mocking. 2) No need for the constructor (EF will create) 3) Model + Id is perfectly fine for Id names. and is even used in MS examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx